# How to determine intervals where $f$ is greater than $g$?

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I have two functions, $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x) = \frac{x^3}{3}$.  I solved for $x$ where $f = g$, finding $x = \pm 6^{1/2}$, then solved for $x$ where $f > g$, $x > \pm 6^{1/2}$, and where $f < g$, $x < \pm 6^{1/2}$. However it is clear there is overlap for where I have stated $f > g$ and $f < g$. How do I show that $f > g$ only when $x \in (0, 6^{1/2})$ and $f < g$ only when $x \in (- 6^{1/2}, 0)$ without graphing?

Completely different approaches from mine are welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the inequality
$$
2x>\frac{x^3}{3}
$$
that can be rewritten as
$$
x(x-\sqrt{6})(x+\sqrt{6})<0
$$
The expression on the left changes sign only at $-\sqrt{6}$, $0$ and $\sqrt{6}$ (where it vanishes). Since its value at $1$ is $-5$ you have the diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_  & -\sqrt{6} &
\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_ & 0 &
\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_ & \sqrt{6} &
\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_ \\
& & & & <0 &
\end{array}
$$
and you can complete it by changing sign at the stated points
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_  & -\sqrt{6} &
\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_ & 0 &
\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_ & \sqrt{6} &
\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_\!\_ \\
<0 & =0 & >0 & =0 & <0 & =0 & >0
\end{array}
$$
So the intervals where the original inequality holds are $(-\infty,-\sqrt{6})$ and $(0,\sqrt{6})$.

Comment: Why is it necessary to know what the value of the 2nd function is at x = 1?

Comment: @galacti-cat97 You just need *one* value besides those where the expression vanishes. I chose $1$, it could be $3$; just choose an “easy” one.

Answer (score 0):

The roots, $x = 0, -\sqrt{6}, +\sqrt{6}$ show merely the crossover points.  You must test the four regions defined by those three points:

- $-\infty < x \leq -\sqrt{6}$
- $-\sqrt{6} \leq x \leq 0$
- $0 \leq x \leq +\sqrt{6}$
- $\sqrt{6} \leq x < \infty$

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the solution $x=0$.

By the *Intermediate Value theorem* the relative positions of the curves can change only at intersection points. Now, for $x\gg 1$, $f(x)<g(x)$, hence we conclude

- if $x>\sqrt 6$, $f(x)<g(x)$,
- if $0<x<\sqrt 6$, $f(x)>g(x)$,
- if $-\sqrt 6<x< $, $f(x)<g(x)$,
- if $x<-\sqrt 6$, $f(x)>g(x)$.

Comment: By "x ≫ 1", do you mean as x approaches 1? How did you come to the conclusion that x = 1 was a significant point to analyze?

Comment: No, it means $x$ tends to $+\infty$ (‘much greater than $1$).